# Fetching Image Url's From Realtime Database - Firebase / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display images onto a collection view. The image url's are saved in the realtime database in Firebase and was wondering, what I am doing wrong? Essentially, users have a node called 'Images' where images they have uploaded are saved inside that node. The names depend on the image Title and the url is the image they have uploaded. Below is my code and a photo of how my database looks like it. If someone could help me out, I would appreciate that a lot. Thanks!

- The Issue is that the images are not being displayed. It is successfully able to display the correct amount of images the user has in their account but does not read the image url. My guess is that because each url is under a different value (imageTitle). Any ideas?

My ViewController:

```
class PicturesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollection: UICollectionView!
    var customImageFlowLayout: CustomImageFlowLayout!
    var images = [UserImages]()
    
    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/Images")
        
        loadDB()      
    }
    
    func loadDB() {
        
        dbRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            var newImages = [UserImages]()
            
            for UserImagesSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                
                let UserImagesObject = UserImages(snapshot: UserImagesSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
                newImages.append(UserImagesObject)
                
            }
            
            self.images = newImages
            self.imageCollection.reloadData()
            
        })
        
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            
        return images.count
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = imageCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        
        let image = images[indexPath.row]
                
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image.url), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "image1"))
        return cell
    }
```

My Array - UserImages

```
struct UserImages {
    
    let key: String!
    let url: String!
    
    let itemsRef: DatabaseReference!
    
    init (url:String, key:String) {
        
        self.key = key
        self.url = url
        self.itemsRef = nil
        
    }
    
    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        
        key = snapshot.key
        itemsRef = snapshot.ref
        
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        
        if let imageUrl = snapshotValue?[""] as? String {
            
            url = imageUrl
                       
        } else {
            
            url = ""
            
        }
    }    
}
```

[image: This is how the realtime database looks like]

Comment: The original code and database structure are missing. Can you put that back in? Otherwise the answer doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    
    if let imageUrl = snapshotValue?[""] as? String {
        
        url = imageUrl
                   
    } else {
        
        url = ""
        
    }
```

with

```
 url = snapshot.value as! String
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your help :)